# Javascript : Swap Two Values

Tags: javascript

I try to swap two values. When I change one value, another value which has same value should be change to first value but the second value is undefined. For example first value is 2 and the second one is 6, if I change 2 to 6, 6 should be 2 but in this case, 6 change to be undefined.
here my code

```
var x = document.getElementById('titleorder['+indexarray+']').value;
var y = this.value;

if (document.getElementById('titleorder['+indexarray+']').onkeyup)
{

    var tmp = x;
    x = y;
    y = tmp;

    document.getElementById('titleorder['+indexarray+']').value = x;
    document.getElementById('titleorder(this.value)').value = y;


}

<input type="text" name="titleorder" id="titleorder[<?PHP echo $row->ORDER; ?>]" value="<?PHP echo $row->ORDER; ?>" size="5" onkeyup="sync(this.value)"/>
```

What's wrong with my code. I hope anybody can help me find out the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

1 Line Code for Swaping in Javascript

```
b = [a, a = b][0];
```

View [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/USdv8/)

Answer (score 2):

```
 document.getElementById('titleorder(this.value)').value = y;
```

In this line, `this.value` is the literal text.  You probably meant to write

```
 this.value = y;
```

Answer (score 1):

The second `titleorder` index & assignment (from `y`), appears to use parentheses where it should use square-brackets.

There appears to be no problem with `x` and `y` swapping, it's the code around it.

It's also unclear what `this.value` will be (if anything) at this point, and you've written it as a literal -- not using it's value.

The `if` statement testing whether `onkeyup` is assigned is unclear.. it's not an event-handler, but it kinda looks like it should be one. I can't see where any event-handlers are in your code, it seems pretty funky.

Comment: Maybe you were _trying_ to write an event handler for `onkeyup`, but I can't be sure and the question/ posted code aren't clear what you're actually trying to do? I suggested this in my answer above, but don't see any further clarification from you. **So: Search for "Javascript event handler examples" or "jQuery event handler examples" on Google,** and come back again when you're ready to ask a question about that.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with this line:

```
document.getElementById('titleorder(this.value)').value = y;
```

First, 'this.value' is used as a string literal instead of a javascript variable value.  Second, you are using parentheses as array indexer.

This should be:

```
document.getElementById('titleorder[' + this.value + ']').value = y;
```

Someone else also pointed out that 'this.value' will not have the same meaning in the second call, because you already assigned the value from 'tmp' into 'y'.  Let's clean the whole thing up a bit:

```
// expects an element to be passed in.
function sync(control)
{
    var elementX = document.getElementById('titleorder['+indexarray+']').value;
    var elementY = control;

    var x = elementX.value
    var y = elementY.value;

    if (elementX.onkeyup)
    {

        var tmp = x;
        x = y;
        y = tmp;

        elementX.value = x;
        elementY.value = y;


    }
} // end function sync

<input type="text" name="titleorder" id="titleorder[<?PHP echo $row->ORDER; ?>]" value="<?PHP echo $row->ORDER; ?>" size="5" onkeyup="sync(this)"/>
```

Comment: I agree with getting the elements into variables, but shouldn't `elementY` be `document.getElementById('titleorder['+this.value+']')` ?? Whether it's right or not I'm unsure, but that's the way the OP's code goes.

Comment: If we have `this` and know it's an element, we already have the element and do not need to get a new reference to it.

Comment: the problem is because i fail to get value of y | var y = this.value; | how is the correct code for change that code?

Comment: @kudo, you should update your script posted.  It looks like you have a `function sync()` wrapper missing, now that I've looked at your html.  I'll update my answer based on what I assume.  This involves changing to `onkeyup="sync(this);"`

Comment: @ThomasW, I think I fixed what you were mentioning.  While you were correct, it is better to just pass in the entire element as `this` instead of `this.value`, so I made the adjustment.  I didn't pay attention to the html onkeyup value, originally.

Answer (score -2):

Simple example to understand it

You only need one temporary variable.

```
var b = list[y];
list[y] = list[x];
list[x] = b;
```

and you can also follow this link:

http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=265